# Adding days to date Uncaught TypeError: getDate is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am taking value from input element and converting it to date format mm/dd/yyyy and then I am adding some days to date but I am getting Uncaught TypeError: dt_cl.getDate is not a function.

```
$('#dt_input').change(function() {
    var dep_dt = $(this).val();
    $('#eff_input').val(dep_dt);
    var eff_dt = new Date(dep_dt);
    var dt_cl = (eff_dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + eff_dt.getDate() + '/' +  eff_dt.getFullYear();
    var exp_dt = new Date().setDate(dt_cl.getDate()+364);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="dt_input">
<input type="text" id="eff_input">
```

Comment: Please add the related HTML.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Added

Comment: Looks like `dt_cl` is a string. It wouldn't have a `getDate()` method.

Comment: @FissureKing Do I need to parse it into int?

Comment: @Jason, See answer from ScottMarcus. You need to convert it to a Date. That said, I'm not sure you're going to end up with the result you want by adding 364 to a day of month...

Comment: @FissureKing Adding 364 to `.getDate()` will work just fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, It won't break; I'd just wonder whether that was what OP was actually trying to do.

Comment: @FissureKing Yes I am trying to add 364 days to chosen date

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `dt_cl` is being initialized to a string here:

```
var dt_cl = (eff_dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + eff_dt.getDate() + '/' +  eff_dt.getFullYear();
```

and then you are calling `getDate()` on it here:

```
var exp_dt = new Date().setDate(dt_cl.getDate()+364);
```

Strings don't have a `getDate()` method. You need to create a new date based on the string and then it will work.

FYI: You many want the first field to be: `<input type="date">` to ensure the input is a valid date format.

```js
$('#dt_input').change(function() {
    var dep_dt = $(this).val();
    $('#eff_input').val(dep_dt);
    var eff_dt = new Date(dep_dt);
    // dt_cl is being set to a string here:
    var dt_cl = (eff_dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + eff_dt.getDate() + '/' +  eff_dt.getFullYear();
    
    // So, you need to take that string and make a new Date from it and then
    // you can call .getDate() on that new date.
    var exp_dt = new Date().setDate(new Date(dt_cl).getDate() + 364);
    
    // The result can be seen by making yet another date using the previous one
    console.log(new Date(exp_dt));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="dt_input">
<input type="text" id="eff_input">
```

Comment: Both Input field should be `text`?

Comment: @NishantDixit As I mentioned in my answer, I'm suggesting that (at least) the first field be a date picker.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `var a = new Date(dt_cl);` something like this?

Comment: @Jason Yes, as you can see, I've incorporated that into my answer

Comment: I get: Number is not assignable to type date

Comment: @Enrico As you can see from my answer, that is not an error with my code. You must have something other than what I'm showing.